# Threading and SQL insert delete strange problem

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading

I have a Windows app, which calls a service and then writes to the database. Before writing results, I delete old data.

The Windows app calls the service using a timer which runs every 5 minutes.

The problem is: even though I am using delete, the code does not delete the records. It works if I call it with out using the timer.

I used transactions, using EF does not work. It still does not delete records.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
        //////Start Timer
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 5 * 60 * 1000; // converts ms to minutes
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(InsertRecords);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timerFired.WaitOne();        
 }

 public void InsertRecords()
 { 
     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstr))
     {
         connection.Open();

         // Delete old entries
         SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction();
         string sql = "Delete  from PhilaMethod ";

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection, trans);
         trans.Commit();
         connection.Close();
     }

     var conn = connectionstr;

     string SQL1 = "";

     foreach (PhilaMethod phila in phila2)
     {
         SQL1 += "INSERT INTO PhilaMethod(Name,PS1,PS2,RSI1,) values ('" + phila.Name + "','"+phila.PS1+"','"+phila.PS2+"','"+phila.RSI1+"','"+phila.RSI2+"'); ";
     }

     string SQL2 = "Delete  from philamethod";

     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
     {
            connection.Open();
            SqlTransaction sqlTran = connection.BeginTransaction();
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.Transaction = sqlTran;

            try
            {
                command.CommandText = SQL2;

                int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if(rowsAffected >= 0)
                {
                    command.CommandText = SQL2;
                    int rowsAffected2 = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if(rowsAffected2 == 0)
                    {
                        command.CommandText = SQL1;
                        rowsAffected += command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                sqlTran.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex1)
            {
                // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
                try
                {
                    sqlTran.Rollback();
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
                    // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
                    // a closed connection.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you clearing `phila2` between runs?  If not, you're reinserting the same data over and over.

Comment: Off topic: this code contains a SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: I'll suggest to call an stored procedure and let this SP to do all DB job.

Comment: You never execute the command that you just created

Comment: The thing is I used a stored proc earlier it did not work. It was not clearing data.

Comment: I used Entity framework earlier, it was not deleteing data. so used this to test. this also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the command.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstr))
    {
        connection.Open();
        // Delete old entries
        SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction();
        string sql = "Delete  from PhilaMethod ";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection, trans);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <--- added this
        trans.Commit();
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: If you look below the code you see I am using ExecutenonQuery it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There're a few issues with your code. You should always dispose disposable objects. Either by calling `Dispose()` or by using a `using {}` block which is the preferred way.

1.) You're not disposing your SqlCommand objects
You should wrap them inside using statements to avoid this mistake and possible memory leaks.

2.) You're not disposing your SqlTransaction objects
You should always wrap that inside using statements to avoid possible memory leaks.

3.) Like others already wrote you have to execute a command. ;)

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstr))
 {
     connection.Open();

     // Delete old entries
     SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction();
     string sql = "Delete  from PhilaMethod ";

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection, trans);
     trans.Commit();
     connection.Close();
 }
```

In this code the execute is missing. ;)
So your code should look like the following. (not tested)

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstr))
 {
     connection.Open();
     // Delete old entries
     using (SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction())
     {
       string sql = "Delete  from PhilaMethod ";
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection, trans))
       {
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // or whatever method you need
       }
       trans.Commit();
     }
     connection.Close();         
 }
```

Comment: Let me try this and I will let you know :) Thanks :)